# How to set properties of pyplot grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not sure of how to phrase this, but how do I set the grid in matplotlib.pyplot so that it appears every 'n' x. Right now the default value of this 'n' is 2, as can be seen here: [pyplot_grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u9SD.png)

But I want the grid to appear at x=0,x=1,x=2... etc., and I want it to appear at y=0,y=1,y=2... etc.

Below is my code for generating that plot.

```
x_values = [1,2,3]
y_values = [1,4,9]

plt.plot(x_values,y_values,'g^')
plt.grid(color='black', linestyle="dotted", linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.xlim(0.0, 12)
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.ylim(0.0, 12)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grid is based on major ticks, so you want to modify your major ticks

```
# setting the ticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(12))
plt.yticks(np.arange(12))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MultipleLocator` class and pass it to `set_major_locator` or `set_minor_locator` to tell the distance of the ticks of the grid:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

x_values = [1,2,3]
y_values = [1,4,9]

plt.plot(x_values,y_values,'g^')
plt.grid(color='black', linestyle="dotted", linewidth=1)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.xlim(0.0, 12)
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.ylim(0.0, 12)
plt.show()
```

This way you dont have to manually specify an iterable of the specific positions where you want the ticks to be. You just tell that they have to be 1 distance appart, and that is all.

Here is the result of the previous code:

[image]

Reference: [Major and minor ticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html) at MatPlotLib website

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to control the "ticks" of the grid, one simple solution is to use plt.xticks(np.arange(12)) and plt.yticks(np.arange(12)) if you want your grid ticks from [0..12].

Comment: Why did you self answer with the same answer that @QuangHoang gave you?